# where to do initialization in tableviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have some instance variables i would like to intialize in my tableviewcontroller.  I already use my nib file to set the table style.  Would i still call initWithStyle: to do the initialization or would i do the initialization in viewDidLoad:?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if your controller is stored inside a nib file, you should use **awakeFromNib**.